# jQuery Caroufredsel issue: swipe events fail when carousel items have links

Tags: jquery, carousel, swipe, caroufredsel

I have a carousel built with the jQuery CarouFredSel plugin.  It works fine. I have added swipe capability as per the site's instructions. I am using the jquery touchswipe plugin.

The issue is when the items in the carousel have hyperlinks (A tags), such as:

```
<ul id="carousel">
   <li><a href="foo.html"><img src="kitten.jpg"/></a><li>
   <li><a href="foo.html"><img src="puppy.jpg"/></a><li>
</ul>
```

This will not swipe, unless you happen to get the space between the images. Then it works.

Oddly, I have also used the Zurb Foundation Orbit slider, and swipe events there work fine even if the images in the slider have links.

Any ideas?  My initialization code:

```
    <script>
    $("#sd").carouFredSel({
        auto        : false,
        responsive  : true,
        scroll      : 4,
        items       : {
            visible : 4,
            width   : 200
        },
        prev: {
            button  : "#sd_prev"
        },
        next: {
            button  : "#sd_next"
        },
        swipe       : {
                onTouch     : true,
                onMouse     : true
            }

    });
</script>
```

EDIT/UPDATE: to show that it will swipe when the cursor is not over an image, see this screenshot:
[image: cursor]

It works as a fiddle, but not in the actual web page.
http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/JqRhb/

Comment: If you only have 2 images the carousel disables arrows, scroll and touch automaticly. You must have more than 4

Comment: Yes, my real one has many.  For the purposes here, i only used 2.

Comment: Sure. The working example is the minimum requirements to work. Can you share a link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: **http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/nAf53/**

**1** - I have added more than 2 items -> Total of 20

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixum.com/75/75" /></a></li>
```

**2** - Added this 3 lines of css so I can float the `<li>`

```
#sd li {display: block;float: left;height: 100px;text-align: center;width: 100px;}
#sd li a {color: #8cabbf;display: block;font: 700 10px/10px Arial;text-decoration: none;}
#sd li a img {border: 1px solid #dfe9ee;}
```

**3** - Import caroufredsel and touchswipe libraries

**4** - Load the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sd").carouFredSel({    
        auto        : true,
        responsive  : true,
        scroll      : 4,
        items       : {
            visible : 4,
            width   : 200
        },
        prev: {
            button  : "#sd_prev"
        },
        next: {
            button  : "#sd_next"
        },
        swipe       : {
                onTouch     : true,
                onMouse     : true
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works there, thanks.  I am really stumped why it refused to work in my page.  I updated the fiddle to use my code, and it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/JqRhb/  But it does not work in the page.  The page is a Foundation 3 page, I am not sure if there is a conflict or something.  The web inspector shows no JS errors.

Comment: Sure can you add all external files from the foundation to your jsfiddle demo? Probably we can see the incompatibility and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a variaton on this problem (swipe works, links do not) and found a workaround using a second touch library as per these instructions: [CarouFredSel Plugin using TouchSwipe with links not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368514/caroufredsel-plugin-using-touchswipe-with-links-not-working)